# What is this function?

Tags: functions, polynomials, computer-science

In python I made this function:

```
def f(x):
    eqStr = ''
    for y in range(int(x)):
        eqStr += 'x**%s + ' % (y)
    eqStr += '0'
    return eval(eqStr)
```

for those who can't read it, what it does is it takes in a number, x, and creates a string (a group of words). Now for y in a list from 0 to x-1 (inclusive) append `x^y +` onto the string. At the end add a zero to fix the last plus. Now compute the string and return it to me.
This is the plot of the function:
[image: my function]
I don't know what this function is and would like to know if it has a name, and if there is a more mathematical way of writing my function.

Comment: I see no point in the string manipulation. One popular Python text I have seen uses eval rather abusively (my opinion).

Comment: @HenningMakholm close but not quite, it is more of $x^0+x^1+x^2+...+x^(x-1)$

Comment: @x-x: Is is a bug that you write "from 0 to x-1", then?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: It has int(x) which coerces $x$ into an integer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes.

Comment: Python: If x is floating point, the conversion (int) truncates towards zero.

Comment: In python, `range(n)` is essentially the sequence 0, 1, 2, … $(n-1)$. So the function is $(x^{\lfloor x\rfloor}-1)/(x-1)$.

Comment: If $x<0$ then range(int(x)) will be empty and the function will evaluate to zero.

Comment: @x-x: To echo Henning's point, there really is no point in creating a string and then evaluating it. If you were to do some symbolic computation then maybe, but you are not. Creating a string adds complexity without any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is some hidden Python-specific point to doing it as string manipulation instead of summing the powers directly, you're computing
$$ f(x) = x^0+x^1+\cdots +x^{x-1}$$

By the usual rule for a finite geometric series this is the same as

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^x-1}{x-1} $$

If $x$ is not necessarily an integer, round it appropriately in the exponent:

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^{\lfloor x\rfloor}-1}{x-1} $$

Comment: less memory usage, maybe faster than first, I was not aware of the second.

Comment: @x-x: You're not seriously claiming that the crazy string manipulation uses less memory or works faster than doing the arithmetic directly? It doesn't. By an enormous margin.

Comment: Then there's garbage collection...

Comment: I'm wrong. )-: *sigh*